# Updating Django ORM with filter is updating unexpected fields

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have a very simple DjangoRestFramework api_view where i am grabbing an id and filtering a queryset by that id and a start date greater than today.

My Model is pretty simple, it has a patient (FK), is_cancelled (boolean), start (Datetime) and end (Datetime).

The issue is that when i run the below update, it is setting the start date to the date and time that i run this view.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def BookingCancelAppointmentsView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        patient_id = request.data
        today = date.today()
        bookings = Booking.objects.filter(patient=patient_id, start__gte=today).update(is_cancelled=True)
    return Response({'message': 'Appointments cancelled'})
```

EDIT: Added Model for reference

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True, related_name='bookings')
    start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    end = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    is_all_day = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_personal = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    practitioner = models.ForeignKey(Practitioner, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='booking_practitioners')

    def __str__(self):
        if not self.patient:
            return self.practitioner.practitioner.get_full_name()

        return str(self.patient.get_full_name())

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('patient', 'start', 'practitioner')
```

so for example, if find an entry that is greater than today for that patient_id, it does update the "is_cancelled" field for the correct record but it is setting the Start datetime from whatever datetime i had in there originally to the date.today() value even though i am only updating the "is_cancelled" field.

Does anyone have any idea why it would touch the "start" field at all and how i might get around this issue?

Software Versions:

- Python Version: 3.10.5
- Django Version: 3.2.15
- Django Rest Framework Version: 3.13.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check your `Booking` model. It might be because you set `auto_now=True` on the `start` field.

Ex.

```py
class Booking(models.Model):
    is_cancelled = models.BooleanField()
    start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

If `auto_now=True` the field will be automatically set to now every time the object is saved

Comment: Hi @istudko thank you for this suggestion but both auto_now and auto_now_add are set to false. I should have shown my model in my question as well

Comment: Oh actually your point made me think and take a look at the database settings. The database itself had "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE" enabled for some reason. I can only guess at some point i did have auto_now set to true and the database didnt update correctly. If you want to update your answer to include checking on the database settings as well, I will mark this one as correct!

Comment: @jAC that's weird. Have u run database migration again after making changes to Booking model?
Normally, the database schema should match your model definition.
You should run database migration from Django
`./manage.py makemigrations` and then `./manage.py migrate` rather than directly changing database schema.

Comment: yeah i did but i had some db problems on my test machine that, tbh, i was too lazy to fix/redo and when you mentioned auto_now i was like ooooo right i have a broke DB :D. my production environment is fine, just didnt take the time to fix my dev box :O lesson is learned lol

Comment: good to hear that production environment is fine LOL :P

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to set the time fields at the time of object creation. You can pass `auto_now_add=True`, instead of `auto_now=True`. 
The `auto_now` will update the field every time the save method is called.

```
class Booking:
    <...other fields here...>
    start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Alternative you can use bulk operations to save data to models. On Bulk operations these fields will not be updated. Though this is not a suggested approach, this is just a hack if you don't want to change your models due to some reasons.

Comment: Hi @vikrant thank you for your suggestion but it is the opposite of what i need :) for some reason it IS updating my start field when updated but i do not want it to do this.